# Rename [accessibilityservice] to [android-accessibilityservice]

Tags: support, retag-request

All android-related tags seem to be prefixed by `android-`. Hence, I think [accessibilityservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accessibilityservice) (whose description reveals is specific to Android) to [android-accessibilityservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-accessibilityservice).

Comment: "android-accessibilityservice" exceeds the maximum tag length.

Comment: Would "android-accessibility" be accurate enough?

Comment: Well, accessibility is more general than the `AccessibilityService`, eg some questions are about the design of the XML layout to support accessibility.